# Execute key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" in every transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using spring framework in my project like this. I'm using spring , hibernate, jasperreport , ibmicu , Microsoft SQL-Server 2019 and other things. I'm confused , cause in every transaction the tables (hibernate entity) are drop and create! my spring-servlet.xml is :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <!--SpringMVC-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.model"/>
<!--    <mvc:annotation-driven/>-->
<!--    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>-->
    <!-- SpringTransaction-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.armanins.model"/><!--ToPackageAddress-->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\MSSQLSERVER\InsuranceDamageDB:1433"/>
        <property name="username" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="pss"/>

    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

and this is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxxyyy</groupId>    
    <artifactId>InsurnceDamageApplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>InsuranceDamage</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
        <spring.version>5.3.9</spring.version>
        <jasper.version>6.17.0</jasper.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.5.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- SQL Server driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0.jre11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- J2EE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mvc</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mvc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- IBM Calendar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>69.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- NetBeans layout -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE113</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>${jasper.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>${jasper.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
            <version>${jasper.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-metadata</artifactId>
            <version>${jasper.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-annotation-processors</artifactId>
            <version>${jasper.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-chart-customizers</artifactId>
            <version>${jasper.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-chart-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${jasper.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-custom-visualization</artifactId>
            <version>${jasper.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.jabolsa.main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>testResources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/generated-groovy-stubs</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <!--                        <arg>-verbose</arg>-->
                        <!--                        <arg>-options,-path</arg>-->
                        <!--                        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>-->
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**but rather in every transaction the**

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"> create-drop </prop>
```

**run again!
why ?!!!**

Comment: Sounds like prototype entity manager.

Comment: @Antoniossss yes my GenericDA is prototype.  so what is the correct way?

Comment: @Antoniossss cause @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

Comment: The problem is that hibernate will execute "auto" whenever you will create an entity manager (Session actually) and you are creating a new one on every transaction

Comment: Probably connction pooling might help

Answer (score 1):

**`create-drop:`** drops the schema when the application is stopped or SessionFactory is closed explicitly.

`<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"> create-drop </prop>`

**`create:`** creates a new schema every time, and destroys previous data.

`<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"> create </prop>`

**`update:`** updates the schema with the current execute query.

`<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"> update </prop>`